# Function as a parameter

Tags: matlab

I have a function in a .m file:

```
function [func diff1 diff2]=fun(x)

func=(3*x^3)+6;
diff1=(3*(x+0.00000001)^3-3*((x)^3))/0.00000001;
diff2=(3*((x+0.00000001)^3)-2*3*(x^3)+3*(x-.00000001)^3)/(.00000001^2);
end
```

In the second function I want to be able to pass in the function as a parameter. I keep getting

> "Attempted to access fun(3); index out of bounds because numel(fun)=1."

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
function [x,N,fval]=halley(fun,guess,tol);
fval=fun(guess);
end
```

Comment: is the `;` in first line of `halley` a typo? how do you invoke `halley`?

Comment: Sorry its a typo. I invoke halley on the command line in Matlab i.e.     halley(fun,3,0.1)

Comment: Seems `fun` is not pointing on your function but on some array, what does `which fun` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function handle when calling `halley`:

```
halley(@fun, 3, 0.1)
```